# change scroll-bar format in Mozilla and I.E like chrome

Tags: css

I want to change scroll-bar color and other properties;
So I wrote the code bellow for chrome:

```
/* Chrome */
.contex#context::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 10px; height: 0px;}

.contex#context::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #800000; }

.contex#context::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #40210f;}

.contex#context::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff;}

.contex#context::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 50px; background-color: #40210f; border-radius: 50%;}


.contex#context::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;}
/* Chrome */
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P92WE/2/)
 and This is [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/P92WE/2/embedded/result/) **if you use chrome you can see right result.**
and I tried this code for **I.E. :**

```
.contex#context {
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:565px;
    height:490px;
    padding-right:5px;
    margin-left:140px;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align:right;
    font-family:"B Koodak",Arial, Sens Serif;
    position:absolute;
  /* I.E scroll-bar */
  scrollbar-face-color: #40210f;
  scrollbar-track: transparant;
  scrollbar-base-color: #40210f;
  scrollbar-face-color: #40210f;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #800000;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFF;
  scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #40210f;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: white;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #800000;
}
```

But it's not enough for my case.
Now I want to change scroll-bar in **I.E** and **Mozila** like I did for chrome.
Specially I want to change **scrollbar-thumb** with **border-radius**[image: like this]
Do you have suggestion for me to make something like this in **FireFox** and **I.E.**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with pure css. I guess you could do it with Javascript if you really need it, though.

Comment: thanks; would you show me an example or some links? I'm searching for a while but couldn't find good samples for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can use is this Jquery Plugin.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html

You will need all of these plugins:

- jquery
- mousewheel
- mwheelIntent
- scrollpane

Once you acquire all of these and implement them, then you can edit the CSS for the scrollbars to what you want. Make sure you use the code provided on that page.

For instance, on the page I provided, these CSS styles can be altered to get what you want.

```
.jspArrow {
background: #800000; // Changed color
text-indent: -20000px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled {
cursor: default;
background: #800000; // Color change, but line not necessary
}

.jspDrag {
background: #40210f; // Changed color
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50%; // Added line
}

.jspTrack {
background: #dde; // Remove this line
position: relative;
}

.jspVerticalBar {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 16px;
height: 100%;
background: red; // Remove this line
}
```

Realize that border-radius does not work on older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I couldn't use this plugin, when I set class names to my html elements, there was strange result!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check out your options here: http://www.unheap.com/?s=scroll

The most popular solution seems to be http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/